# Switching View Controllers In Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, xcode5, modalviewcontroller

There used to be an option in Xcode 4 to do the MODAL where you hold control and move from the button to the knew controller, but that option doesn't seem to be there anymore, and i haven't found a new way to move from controller to controller. Any Suggestions. willing to post code but don't have any pertaining to this senerio at the time.

EDIT*

Looking further into the situation, i believe the option isn't redly available to me, because i started with a blank project,instead of a different one that may have the option already programmed in. Also, this is in a .xib file that i created. Thanks!

*EDIT AGAIN

For future developers encountering the same problem, you need to have a storyboard, not a .xib file. The problem i was having was that i have a .xib file, and couldn't use the transition i was looking for. Make sure when creating your project that you have the options you want. thanks for everyone that helped and good luck to all.

Comment: As @confuseddeer has said, adding a segue from 1 vc to another in a storyboard has not changed really. if you want to make the segue modal, just be sure to set that as the transition style.

Comment: Like I said: Add a view controller by drag and drop in STORYBOARD.

Answer (score 1):

Add a view controller by drag and drop in storyboard.
Once the second view controller has been added to the storyboard, add a button to the first view controller,press and hold control and then left click on the button in the first view controller and drag (a blue line should appear) to an open space in the second view controller. Select modal option when the pop up appears. It works for me.

Comment: i don't have a modal option in my Xcode. when i drag and hold control like you said it doesn't allow me to let go above the 2nd view controller.